# How to do calculation within Linq select block?

Tags: linq, select

How do I do the price conversion within this LINQ select?
Let's say I want the selected price to be 1.5 times the price I read in from the xml file. Where do I do this multiplication?

```
select new
       {
           Price = double.Parse(d.Element(price).Value).ToString(),
           ProductName = d.Element(productName).Value
       }
```

I was hoping for something like this, but obviously, that's an error:

```
Price = double.Parse(d.Element(price).Value * 1.5).ToString(),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
Price = (double.Parse(d.Element(price).Value) * 1.5).ToString()
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess the `ToString()` was a typo, so

```
select new
{
  Price = double.Parse(d.Element(price).Value) * 1.5,
  ProductName = d.Element(productName).Value
}
```

If not, it would be as Sergey says, however I'd advise you to change your data model to actually contain a double for `Price` (or even better, `decimal` as double isn't accurate enough for money).